# Dynamically updating single field in model

Tags: javascript, node.js, adonis.js

I'm using adonisjs and there is a problem with my update method:

```
async update(id, data) {
  const user = await User.find(id);
  user.merge(data);
  return await user.save();
}
```

For some reason, the merge method doesn't modify the provided fields (data is an object with the fields I want to update and its new values) but updates everything... including the hashed user's password which is a big problem for me. I don't want to do such a thing, just update the provided fields. Is there a way to fix it?

---

I've stoped the application, served it once again and created a fresh new database just to be sure. It keeps updating fields that shouldn't be edited. Later, if the user tries to log in, it gets the next error message (obviously):

```
{
    "message": "auth/login/error",
    "error": "E_PASSWORD_MISMATCH: Cannot verify user password"
}
```

Images displaying the user's password being updated:

Before the update:
[image: Before being updated]

After the update:
[image: After being updated]

Comment: Just a guess... `data = user.merge(data)`

Comment: And what would i do with that `data` variable?

Comment: omg.. my bad... `user = user.merge(data)`

Comment: It throws an error: `Cannot read property 'save' of undefined`

Comment: try this await user.save() and then return user object

Answer (score 1):

What's up?

So, you can just update values instead of replacing it, for example:

```js
  user.name = "foo"
```

in the end

```js
  await user.save()
```

Comment: Sure thing, but it would be a manual update, I want to have a single method that would be able to update any field.

Comment: If you are using adonis, it`s a good thing to put parameters?

Comment: Try to console log data, id and user

Comment: What have in data object?

Comment: The `data` object looks like this: `{ verified: true }`